# Load a custom XIB for expanded cell in tableView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to load a expanded cell XIB for a `UITableViewCell` when it is selected.The content of my normal cell and expanded cell is almost same except for the extra space where I would populate some views in expanded cell.Now to differentiate between the normal cell and expanded cell I have changed the `UILabel` colors inside the expanded cells to a different color.I am able to load the expanded cell XIB on clicking a cell **however** the **problem** is that **every cell is getting replaced by expanded cell XIB** .The only difference is that the height of clicked cell is more than others .And when I click back the expanded cell, Normal cell `XIB`'s are loaded again.How can I load the expanded cell `XIB` only for the clicked cell? Or is there a better way to achieve this thing?

Here's how I am expanding the cell.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {

    [self.expandedCells removeAllObjects];
    isExpanded = NO;
    [self.busTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.busTableView reloadData];
    [self.busTableView endUpdates];

}else{
    isExpanded=YES;

    if (self.expandedCells.count>0) {
        [self.expandedCells removeAllObjects];
    }

    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
    expCell.expContainer.hidden=YES;

     //Some more code

    [self.busTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.busTableView reloadData];
    [self.busTableView endUpdates];

   }

}
```

And the `cellForRow` method looks like this.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  if (!isExpanded) {   //BOOL variable set to NO in viewDidLoad initially

    BusListCell *cell =(BusListCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell==nil) {
    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BusListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nibs[0];

    }
    cell.busName.text = [[busArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"operatorName"];

    return cell;

 }else{
      expCell = (ExpandedCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
      if (expCell==nil) {
         NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ExpandedCell" owner:self options:nil];
        expCell = nibs[0]; 

       }

       expCell.bus_Name.text = [[busArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"operatorName"];
       return expCell;

      }

    return nil;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (!isExpanded) {}
```

you have to check

```
if (![self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]){}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton .Saved me a lot of time :-)